# mouse in gnuplot x11

Tags: zooming, gnuplot, x11

I noticed that I can use the right button of the mouse in order to zoom in a plot in gnuplot, with the terminal X11.

I don't find any documentation for the other mouse gesture.
For example, it would be fine to do some zoom out!
Could you suggest this?

Best,

Al.

---

EDIT:
Apparently, the only possibility is to zoom in with the right mouse button and use the key p to come back, as Christoph suggested.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, the documentation is not very clear about this. You can find some information about this under `help mouse` (type this in the interactive gnuplot terminal, or see the section `Mouse` in the pdf). This shows you for example, that you can use the mouse wheel for scrolling in x and y direction as well as zooming (`help mouse scrolling`).

To get all the gestures, type `show bind`, which gives me (Linux, 4.6.4):

```
gnuplot> show bind

 2x<B1>             print coordinates to clipboard using `clipboardformat`
                    (see keys '3', '4')
 <B2>               annotate the graph using `mouseformat` (see keys '1', '2')
                    or draw labels if `set mouse labels is on`
 <Ctrl-B2>          remove label close to pointer if `set mouse labels` is on
 <B3>               mark zoom region (only for 2d-plots and maps).
 <B1-Motion>        change view (rotation). Use <ctrl> to rotate the axes only.
 <B2-Motion>        change view (scaling). Use <ctrl> to scale the axes only.
 <Shift-B2-Motion>  vertical motion -- change xyplane
 <wheel-up>         scroll up (in +Y direction).
 <wheel-down>       scroll down.
 <shift-wheel-up>   scroll left (in -X direction).
 <shift-wheel-down>  scroll right.
 <control-wheel-up>  zoom in toward the center of the plot.
 <control-wheel-down>   zoom out.
 <shift-control-wheel-up>  zoom in only the X axis.
 <shift-control-wheel-down>  zoom out only the X axis.

Space          raise gnuplot console window
 q            * close this plot window

 a              `builtin-autoscale` (set autoscale keepfix; replot)
 b              `builtin-toggle-border`
 e              `builtin-replot`
 g              `builtin-toggle-grid`
 h              `builtin-help`
 l              `builtin-toggle-log` y logscale for plots, z and cb for splots
 L              `builtin-nearest-log` toggle logscale of axis nearest cursor
 m              `builtin-toggle-mouse`
 r              `builtin-toggle-ruler`
 1              `builtin-previous-mouse-format`
 2              `builtin-next-mouse-format`
 3              `builtin-decrement-clipboardmode`
 4              `builtin-increment-clipboardmode`
 5              `builtin-toggle-polardistance`
 6              `builtin-toggle-verbose`
 7              `builtin-toggle-ratio`
 n              `builtin-zoom-next` go to next zoom in the zoom stack
 p              `builtin-zoom-previous` go to previous zoom in the zoom stack
 u              `builtin-unzoom`
 Right          `builtin-rotate-right` only for splots; <shift> increases amount
 Up             `builtin-rotate-up` only for splots; <shift> increases amount
 Left           `builtin-rotate-left` only for splots; <shift> increases amount
 Down           `builtin-rotate-down` only for splots; <shift> increases amount
 Escape         `builtin-cancel-zoom` cancel zoom region
```

Comment: this help would be great! Unfortunately "show bind" is not valid in my gnuplot. I am only able to use the right button to zoom in! Gnuplot version is "4.2 patchlevel 6", terminal x11

Comment: It seems that this was introduced in version 4.4.3, from its NEWS file: `NEW Implement pan and zoom via mouse wheel.`

Comment: But I can still zoom in using the right button. No way to zoom out?

Comment: You can unzoom using e.g. `p`, which goes to the previous zoom settings.

Comment: Is there anyway to follow the curve with the mouse? It would be great to somehow get the mouse cursor to snap to the closest curve, and be able to see exact X,Y coordinates and not just an approximation, trying to stay close to the curve.

Answer (score -1):

I know this is an old post, but I've been having the trouble of the graph being too large for the gnuplot window (Version 4.6 patchlevel 6).

The solution I found was to hold down the scroll wheel and pan left or right to zoom out and in respectively.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Then you are doing something else wrong. Not suited as answer to this question